# Issue on Replacing Special Characters in a <pre> Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a jQuery Plugin for highlighting my Snippet at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/h14sbLz0/)  but the browser assumes that

```
<pre class="php">
  <?php     
      echo "My first PHP script!"; 
  ?> 
 </pre>
```

is a originally PHP code which it is! now the solution is replacing  all  <  with  `&lt;`  and  >  with  `&gt;`

inside the  `<pre class="php"></pre>`

Now can you please let me know how can I use the jQuery to replace all < and > characters inside the  with `&lt;` and `&gt;` before loading the page?

Thanks

Comment: it is not browser it is php interpreter running on the server use `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<>`  jQuery will not help this, configure your web server to make it not to interpret the content (other way would be to use something like  `echo <<<EOL` )

Comment: Thanks eicto, I will update the post,

Comment: see updated comment,

Comment: I gues configuring the server is not a good solution as I need to run real PHP file as well!

Comment: As I said if you replace the <> characters with `&lt;` and `&gt;` the snippet highlighter works perfectly

Comment: oh, you should get difference between serverside and clientside scripts... just wrap your code with something that will not interpret code samples...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72792/discussion-between-eicto-and-suffii).

Comment: PHP runs at the server, and JS runs at the client. Therefore, JS can't know the PHP code used. This must be fixed server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you got the data with `<?` tags, it better for you is to replace output of your code serverside with `&lt;` and `&gt;` but if you looking for dirty js solution it is would be:

```
$('.php').each(function() {
    var $this=$(this);
    $this.text($this.html().replace(/\<\!--\?([\s\S]*?)-->/g,'<?$1>'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/x974w2d9/

I not remember if any browser do the replacing of the `<?` with `<!--?` but chrome does. The js solution will not work if you have some random examples like: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/x974w2d9/2/.

Answer (score 0):

> Now can you please let me know how can I use the jQuery to replace all < and > characters inside the with < and > before loading the page?

The problem lies in the assumption behind this question. You cannot use jQuery to make this manipulation *before* the page loads, as jQuery executes after the page loads up in the browser. So your PHP is getting executed and all jQuery will see is:

```
<pre class="php">
  My first PHP script!
</pre>
```

You need to make sure the string makes it into the output instead of being executed. Something like this should work:

```
<pre class="php">
  <?php
      $snippet = <<<EOT
<?php
    echo "My first PHP script!";
?>
EOT;
      echo $snippet;
  ?>
</pre>
```